# Writing to a file in C++ space acts as a new line

Tags: c++

Here's the code :

```
cout << "Enter file location:";
cin >> location;
string line;
ofstream writefile(location);
if (writefile.is_open())
{
    while (q==1)
    {
        i++;
        cin >> lines[i];
        if (lines[i] == "end")
        {
            lines[i] = "";
            q = 0;
        }
    }
    while (writeindex<i)
    {
        writeindex++;
        writefile << lines[writeindex] << "\n";
    }
    writefile.close();
}
else cout << "Unable to open file";
return 0;
```

I enter:
WritePad are amazing
asd asd
The file that I write :
WritePad
are
amazing
asd
asd
This is not the way it should . Help!

Comment: `cin >> lines[i];` uses all whitespaces to delimit the input, not just newline characters.

Comment: `cin >> lines[i];` reads single words, you should use `getline()` to read whole lines.

Comment: Actually in your code **reading** from a file – not writing to a file — space acts like newline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`operator>>` for `std::cin` uses whitespace as a delimiter, so instead of reading a whole line, you are just reading a single word. To fix this, use `std::getline` instead.

```
std::getline(cin, lines[i]);
```